# How does this EXCEPT work in MS SQL in the following example

Tags: sql-server

i am farily new to MS SQL, but I am having to work with it more and more now. I have come across something, someone has written before and didnt write any docs to it.. ( lucky me... ) and I just cant seem to wrap my head around this statement:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION loadMissingAllocations
    INSERT INTO @missingAllocs
    SELECT * FROM @absAllocs
    EXCEPT
    SELECT * FROM @ttaAllocs
    SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @eventDetails = 'End loadMissingAllocations: ' + CAST(@rowCount as VARCHAR(10)) + ' rows affected';
COMMIT TRANSACTION loadMissingAllocations
```

So, it looks like we are selecting everything from absALLOCS and are inserting it into missingALLOCS but the EXCEPT, for me, seems to be totally out of place... I understand something like:

"Select everything from x except everything from y and put it into z".

This cant be the case, right?

Thank you for your guidance! :)

Comment: `EXCEPT` is relational subtraction. The results of the second set are removed from the results of the first set. The remainder are inserted into `@missingAllocs`.

Comment: `SELECT .. EXCEPT SELECT ...` is a valid statement on its own; the result of that is then used as the source for the `INSERT`.

Comment: [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) manual.. you can also replace EXCEPT generally with `SELECT DISTINCT... WHERE ... NOT IN(SELECT .. )`  or  `SELECT DISTINCT table1.* FROM table1. LEFT JOIN table2 WHERE table2.colum IS NULL AND ...`

Comment: @RaymondNijland: that's true only if there are key columns available for a join. `EXCEPT` will treat `NULL` values "the right way" (that is, it matches `NULL` with `NULL` for purposes of determining whether rows are the same), so it can be used whether or not there is a natural way to join the tables, and is much more convenient in that case.

Comment: indeed @JeroenMostert using LEFT JOIN to replace is a bit tricky because EXPECT handles NULL different i forgot about that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right.

"Select everything from x except everything from y and put it into z".

Translating this into tables would mean:

```
SELECT EVERYTHING FROM @absAllocs
EXCEPT 
WHAT ALREADY EXISTS IN @ttaAllocs
AND
STORE THAT RESULT IN @missingAllocs
```

or

Everything that exists in `@absAllocs` but does not exist in `@ttaAllocs`, save into `@missingAllocs`.

Answer (score 1):

Nice visual representation of the EXCEPT clause in the link.

https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sqlserver-18-how-to-use-the-except-operator/

EXCEPT basically removes the common elements from the two tables and takes no elements from the second table.

Comment: Okay, so my thought was actually not much off, was it?